# Is there a name for the Ruby syntax shared by attr methods, ActiveRecord associations, the "content_type" Sinatra property, etc.?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I noticed that all 3 of these "things" use a similar syntax, i.e. "name1" followed by a symbol:

Example 1:

```
attr_reader :methodname
```

Example 2:

```
before_create :dothisthing
```

Example 3:

```
content_type :json
```

Is there specific jargon I can use to refer to this syntax pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been informed that the above syntax is really syntactic sugar for a regular method call.  For instance:

```
erb :index, :layout => false
```

is really the same as:

```
erb(:index, {:layout => false})
```

And all the above examples mentioned simply take advantage of this sugar.  This makes sense to me but a 2nd opinion from the S.O. community wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard these referred to as 'class macros', especially in the context of Rails, but what they are all essentially class methods that write other class or instance methods (i.e, metaprogramming).

Answer (score 0):

The thing they all have in common is that they use :symbols. But of those three, I think only attr_reader is part of the core language.